# Flow upload file component

Tags: visual-workflow, fileupload

I create a flow which allows the user to upload a file, for this case I use the lightning component "file upload". I also create two required custom fields and I add the fields also to the flow. But how can I transfer these fields to the upload file? At the moment a get always an error, because the required fields not filled. I found a workaround to add a record type to the object Content Version, if I add a record type to this object, it appear a dialog to add the required information. But for this dialog I can't change the layout.

If this works, can I replace the standard files upload dialog?

Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: You may need to use a custom file upload component due to limitations with the standard. I believe the standard has a set of predefined fields and doesn't reflect the ContentDocument/Version Layout.

Comment: this might help - https://www.issacc.com/advanced-lightning-file-upload-component/